# Error:Adding Unchase OData Connected Service to the project failed: Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, odata, s4hana

I am trying to use https://github.com/unchase/Unchase.OData.Connectedservice/ to generate OData client C# code based on a metadata file.
The service is hosted on SAP S/4HANA and the metadata is in version 2.0.
Here is the content of the metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0"
    xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_AGGREGATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Aggregation.V1" Alias="Aggregation"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_ANALYTICS',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Analytics.v1" Alias="Analytics"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_CAPABILITIES',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1" Alias="Capabilities"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_CODELIST',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.CodeList.v1" Alias="SAP__CodeList"/>
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.CodeList.v1" Alias="CodeList"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMON',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMUNICATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Communication.v1" Alias="Communication"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_MEASURES',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Measures.V1" Alias="Measures"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_PERSONALDATA',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.PersonalData.v1" Alias="PersonalData"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_UI',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1" Alias="UI"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap/opu/odata/iwfnd/catalogservice;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_VALIDATION',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='EM_CORE')/$value"
        xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Validation.V1" Alias="Validation"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema Namespace="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV" xml:lang="en" sap:schema-version="1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <Annotation Term="Core.SchemaVersion" String="1.0.0"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm"/>
            <EntityType Name="A_CompanyCodeType" sap:label="Company Code" sap:content-version="1">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="CompanyCode"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="CompanyCode" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Company Code"/>
                <Property Name="CompanyCodeName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="Company Name" sap:quickinfo="Name of Company Code or Company"/>
                <Property Name="CityName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="City"/>
                <Property Name="Country" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Country/Region Key"/>
                <Property Name="Currency" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5" sap:label="Currency" sap:quickinfo="Currency Key" sap:semantics="currency-code"/>
                <Property Name="Language" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:label="Language Key"/>
                <Property Name="ChartOfAccounts" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Chart of Accounts"/>
                <Property Name="FiscalYearVariant" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Fiscal Year Variant"/>
                <Property Name="Company" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Company"/>
                <Property Name="CreditControlArea" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Credit control area"/>
                <Property Name="CountryChartOfAccounts" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Alternative COA" sap:quickinfo="Alternative Chart of Accounts"/>
                <Property Name="FinancialManagementArea" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="FM Area" sap:quickinfo="Financial Management Area"/>
                <Property Name="AddressID" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Address"/>
                <Property Name="TaxableEntity" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Taxes on Sls/Purc." sap:quickinfo="Taxes on Sales/Purchases Group"/>
                <Property Name="VATRegistration" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="VAT Registration No." sap:quickinfo="VAT Registration Number"/>
                <Property Name="ExtendedWhldgTaxIsActive" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Extended WTax Active" sap:quickinfo="Indicator: Extended Withholding Tax Active"/>
                <Property Name="ControllingArea" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Controlling Area"/>
                <Property Name="FieldStatusVariant" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Field status variant" sap:quickinfo="Field Status Variant"/>
                <Property Name="NonTaxableTransactionTaxCode" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Output Tax Code" sap:quickinfo="Output Tax Code for Non-Taxable Transactions"/>
                <Property Name="DocDateIsUsedForTaxDetn" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Tax Determ.with Doc.Date" sap:quickinfo="Indicator: Document Date As the Basis for Tax Determination"/>
                <Property Name="TaxRptgDateIsActive" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Tax Date" sap:quickinfo="Tax Reporting Date Active in Documents"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:message-scope-supported="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
                <EntitySet Name="A_CompanyCode" EntityType="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV.A_CompanyCodeType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
            </EntityContainer>
            <Annotations Target="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV.API_COMPANYCODE_SRV_Entities"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
                <Annotation Term="Common.ApplyMultiUnitBehaviorForSortingAndFiltering" Bool="true"/>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV.API_COMPANYCODE_SRV_Entities"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
                <Annotation Term="Capabilities.BatchSupported" Bool="false"/>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="API_COMPANYCODE_SRV.API_COMPANYCODE_SRV_Entities/A_CompanyCode"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
                <Annotation Term="Capabilities.ReadRestrictions">
                    <Record>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Description" String="Reads the items of all company codes."/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="LongDescription" String="Reads the company codes available in your system."/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ReadByKeyRestrictions">
                            <Record>
                                <PropertyValue Property="Description" String="Reads a company code by key."/>
                                <PropertyValue Property="LongDescription" String="Reads a selected company code for the provided company code key."/>
                            </Record>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <atom:link rel="self" href="https://sap-s4odata/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_COMPANYCODE_SRV/$metadata"
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
            <atom:link rel="latest-version" href="https://sap-s4odata/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_COMPANYCODE_SRV/$metadata"
                xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The following steps show how I imported the metadata file:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see on the last step I have received an error.

I also tried to import https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata file and it generated OData client without any error.

Comment: Stuck at exactly same issue, did you find some solution?